# batch script to disable/move/delete multiple computers in AD

Tags: windows, batch-file, active-directory

I'm currently working in an organization that has migrated their OU groups so that everything belongs to a parent folder called "users and workstations".

This is a slight problem for me, as I have a few batch scripts that delete users and computers from a text file - something that I run fairly regularly.

The current code I use, for example, to disable a batch of machines is below

```
@echo off 
CLS
ECHO Now Disabling Machines...
TIMEOUT 2 > nul
Pause
FOR /f %%i in (%~dp0\computernames.txt) do ( 
dsquery computer -name %%i | dsmod computer -disabled Yes
)
```

If I run this code since the change, I get the following error

```
dsmod failed:'Target object for this command' is missing.
type dsmod /? for help.
```

However, if I manually type the dsquery / dsmod line of code into command prompt and replace the "%%i" with a computer that failed, it succeeds.

I'm almost certain that this is due to the spaces within the OU folder structures, but don't know what to do to change my script to continue working.

Is there a way to change it? should I try something else? I'm going crazy trying to figure this out!!!

Thanks in advance,

Ben

P.S. I've come up with a solution that seems to work - I'll keep this open incase anyone can suggest a better way to do what i need to do. Please see below for the code that works for me. Looks like I needed to add correct delims and two sets of double-quotes to exit out correctly.... it doesn't make too much sense to me... but it works...

```
@echo off
setlocal disabledelayedexpansion


CLS
ECHO Now Disabling Machines...
ECHO.
Pause
FOR /f "delims= " %%i in (%~dp0\computernames.txt) do ( 
echo disabling %%i && echo. && dsquery computer -name ""%%i"" | dsmod computer -disabled Yes && echo.
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see original post for solution.

disabling delayed expansion and specifying the delims, along with double double quoting the variable seems to have fixed the problem!

Answer (score 0):

Try using quotes on %%i in this line like this

```
dsquery computer -name "%%i" | dsmod computer -disabled Yes
```

Edit (added below):
Ahhhh... I bet the current directory is not what you think.  Perhaps you are executing from a UNC drive.  Try this:

```
pushd %~dp0
FOR /f %%i in (computernames.txt) do ( 
   dsquery computer -name "%%i" | dsmod computer -disabled Yes
)
```

Comment: no luck @RGuggisberg - I've tried commenting list results out before with no luck, but this time I got the same error

`dsmod failed:'Target object for this command' is missing.`

Comment: nope, definitely running it from a mapped drive. so its pulling the values from the text file OK.. I believe I might have fixed it by disabling delayedexpansion and double quoting the %%i... as shown below this seems to be working OK for the time being...

`@echo off
setlocal disabledelayedexpansion

CLS
ECHO Now Disabling Machines...
TIMEOUT 2 > nul
Pause
FOR /f "delims= " %%i in (%~dp0\computernames.txt) do ( 
echo disabling %%i && echo. && dsquery computer -name ""%%i"" | dsmod computer -disabled Yes && echo.
)`

Comment: Good catch on disabling delayed expansion.  You don't need it for the code you have shown.  Enabling it would definitely cause it to not work if there was an ! in the computernames.txt.